# How to write a drop down list to a file in webdriver/java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I tried giving the string in the code, but I have a requirement where a txt file has to be added to java and from there read the text and compare it with the items in the array. In array we will have drop down list items.

Without using string in the txt, can I read the same string from the txt file and compare with array?

Here is the code:

```
    driver.get("http://www.depreportingservices.state.pa.us/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fOil_Gas%2fOil_Gas_Well_Historical_Production_Report");
    WebElement mSelectElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue']"));
    List<WebElement> optionsList = mSelectElement.findElements(By.tagName("optio driver.get("http://www.depreportingservices.state.pa.us/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fOil_Gas%2fOil_Gas_Well_Historical_Production_Report");
    WebElement mSelectElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue']"));
    List<WebElement> optionsList = mSelectElement.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
    Wait(20000);
    String oldMonth = "E:\\Ashik\\wkspSelenium\\Stackcode\\Month";
    String line = null;
    String loc="E:\\Ashik\\wkspSelenium\\Stackcode\\Month";
    try {
    // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
     FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(oldMonth);

    // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

    for (int i = 2; i < optionsList.size(); i++) {
    WebElement element = optionsList.get(i);
    String newMonth = element.getText();

    if (!oldMonth.equals("All") && !newMonth.equals("All")) {

    if (newMonth.equals(oldMonth)) {
    // IF the string are same, nthng we need to do
    } 
    else if (!newMonth.equals(oldMonth)) {
    /*
    * If the string are not same,then i.e., considered as new Month, download the new month details*/
    element.click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl00']")).click();
    Wait(200000);
    //Click on File save button
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Button']")).click();
    //wait time to load the options
     Wait(20000);
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Menu']/div[2]/a")).click();
    Wait(10000);
    System.out.println(  "New month data downloaded in csv format:==>"+newMonth);
    break;
    } 
    } 
    oldMonth = newMonth;
    // String fstream=newMonth;
    } 
    System.out.println(line);
    }   

    // Always close files.
    bufferedReader.close();         
    }
     catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.println("Unable to open file '" +  oldMonth + "'");                
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
     System.out.println("Error reading file '" + oldMonth + "'");  


 // Or we could just do this: ex.printStackTrace();
 }  
//fstream(fstream1);
FileWriter newMonth = new FileWriter(loc);    
}
```

Comment: What error/exception you are facing?

Comment: not error, but unable to think logically how to overwrite the txt of selected month from drop down to the same txt file.

Comment: i am successfull till reading file from that txt file, but after selecting a month from drop down, how to overwrite that Month txt to the same file?

Comment: String oldMonth = "E:\\Ashik\\wkspSelenium\\Stackcode\\Month";
       String line = null;
       String loc="E:\\Ashik\\wkspSelenium\\Stackcode\\Month";
       try {
              // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
              FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(oldMonth);

              // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
              BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
              
              while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

Comment: I suggest that you use excel instead of txt file.

Comment: for (int i = 2; i < optionsList.size(); i++) {
           WebElement element = optionsList.get(i);
           String newMonth = element.getText();
           
           if (!oldMonth.equals("All") && !newMonth.equals("All")) {
           
            
            
            if (newMonth.equals(oldMonth)) {
             
             
            // IF the string are same, nthng we need to do
            } else if (!newMonth.equals(oldMonth)) {
            /*
            * If the string are not same,then i.e., considered as new
            * Month, download the new month details
          */

Comment: element.click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl00']")).click();
            Wait(200000);
              //Click on File save button
              driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Button']")).click();

Comment: Wait(20000);
              driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Menu']/div[2]/a")).click();
             
              Wait(10000);
              
            
            System.out.println(  "New month data downloaded in csv format:==>"+newMonth);
            break; } } 
           
               oldMonth = newMonth;
             // String fstream=newMonth;
           } 
               
                  System.out.println(line);
              }

Comment: bufferedReader.close();         
          }
          catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
              System.out.println("Unable to open file '" +  oldMonth + "'");                
          }
          catch(IOException ex) {
              System.out.println("Error reading file '" + oldMonth + "'");                  
              // Or we could just do this: 
              // ex.printStackTrace();
              
              
       
 }
      
       //fstream(fstream1);
       FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(loc);

Comment: this is how it is working, but not pverwriting the new month(ex: oct )to that txt

Comment: why excel, why not txt file? But excel or txt both should work in the same way right?

Comment: in excel you can check by cell num that if data is exist or not? in txt file not sure how you will check. There are many benefits of excel.

Comment: ok could you please help me with excel way of doing this? and overwriting the selected month to txt file

Comment: You may want to explore [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/)